# Getting API application "{0}" invalid with eBay API in .Net

Tags: .net, ebay-api

I am getting the

> API application "{0}" invalid" error

which suppose to mean that I have the platform all wrong.

However, I created sandbox keys and as you see from the data below, I am using sandbox addresses.

Can somebody help please?

- ApiContext  {eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiContext}  eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiContext
- ApiCredential   {eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiCredential}   eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiCredential
- ApiLogManager   {eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiLogManager}   eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.ApiLogManager

  ```
  CallMetricsTable    Nothing eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.CallMetricsTable
  CallRetry   Nothing eBay.Service.Core.Sdk.CallRetry
  EnableMetrics   False   Boolean
  EPSServerUrl    "https : //api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll" String
  ErrorLanguage   en_GB {5}   eBay.Service.Core.Soap.ErrorLanguageCodeType
  LastCallTime    #12:00:00 AM#   Date
  RuleName    ""  String
  RuName  ""  String
  SignInUrl   "https : //signin.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn" String
  Site    UK {2}  eBay.Service.Core.Soap.SiteCodeType
  SoapApiServerUrl    "https : //api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi"  String
  Timeout 60000   Integer
  TotalCalls  2   Integer
  Version "1031"  String
  WebProxy    Nothing System.Net.IWebProxy
  XmlApiServerUrl Nothing String
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the Developer, Application, and Certificate key, you also need the eBayToken, OR you are getting "API application "{0}" invalid" error.